# Run script on GCP instance terminate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to execute the shutdown script in case GCP compute instance is deleted by any means. I dont want to execute it in case instance is stopped.

Is there any way to achieve this please?

I am new to GCP and really dont have any clue if there is anything which can help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Sanjiv

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an implementation for startup scripts and one for [shutdown scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript) for instances that run compatible images.

Bot types of scripts can be entered in the instance metadata directly [through the GUI or the cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#provide_shutdown_script_contents_directly)  or, in a more tidy way, you can upload the script file to one of your buckets and provide the url with the key ["startup-script-url"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#shutdownscriptstorage)

Comment: Jordi thanks for quick response. But that shutdown script will execute if you shutdown or restart an instance. I would like to execute it only on node termination.

Comment: If you want this for Kubernetes then it's not yet officially implemented, but this project might be helpful: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-node-termination-handler